# SAS text to date format

Tags: sas, date-conversion

I have a very basic question in SAS

I have the following macro variable which is in text format, I want to convert to a date format...not too sure how to do this:

```
%let mydt = 06/30/1999;
```

How do I convert this into a date format so that^

```
%let mydtnew = "06/30/1999"d;
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: What's wrong with %let mydtnew = "06/30/1999"d?  This will store the value as a date

Comment: @Keith Actually, it will not - for two reasons.  One, it would need to be "30JUN1999"d; but even if it were, it still stores that text in the macro variable, which then (usually) would be converted to a numeric value upon use (but the macro variable still technically contains the text, not the number).

Comment: @Joe it's a fair comment. I was aware that all macro variables are stored as text, but didn't know that only certain formats, e.g. 'ddmmmyyyy'd were converted to dates at run time.  My point was that it seems unnecessary to store a date in one format in a %let statement and then have to write code to convert it to a different format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - is that what you were after?

```
%let mydt = 06/30/1999;

%let mydt2  = %sysfunc(inputn(&mydt,mmddyy10.));

%put &mydt2;
```

Comment: Wouldn't mydt2 store the numeric value rather the formatted date value?

Comment: At the moment I'm not quite sure what's being requested. Let's wait for the asker to respond.

Comment: This does what I wanted it stores it in the numeric value which is still fine for my purpose. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Note that in SAS, date literals should follow DDMMMYYYY (date9.) format.
So, you could use something like this:

```
%let mydtnew = %sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(inputn(&mydt., MMDDYY10.)), date9.));
```

The inner most `%sysfunc` is telling SAS that the date is in mm/dd/yyyy format - at this stage that text date is stored as a number. The outer `%sysfunc`is telling SAS to take the numeric date and format it into date9. format.

Note: mydtnew  will store date without the double quotes or the `d` at the end. Usuall practice is to add the quotes and the `d` at the time you use the macro, such as

```
where account_open_date>="&mydtnew."d
```